# AsyncStorage module not found in /expo/build/Notifications

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I'm getting the below mentioned error when i try run application in the web mode.

```
/node_modules/expo/build/Notifications/Notifications.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/AsyncStorage' in '/Users/i322865/node_modules/expo/build/Notifications'
```

I'm using the latest expo(0.36, same error i faced when i was using 0.35 version as well) and react native web 0.12.0-rc.1. Please help to solve this issue and let me know if you require any further details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This module (AsyncStorage) is not available on **react-native-web : ^0.12**.

If you need to use the AsyncStorage you can use the version: **"react-native-web": "0.11.7",**

PS: you can check updates on that subject at this issue: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1515

The official position is:

```
Use 0.11 until the community packages add web support. 
They've known this was coming for 9 months react-native-community/async-storage#52
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you. I will check and let you know

Comment: Hello. I added the dependency "react-native-web": "0.11.7", in my package.json and I still get the error 
"Attempted import error: 'AsyncStorage' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.".
 I guess it is the same issue as above. Do you know what could be my issue?